# Python logger message collision when running in threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, amazon-cloudwatch, python-logging

Using modules *threading* and *logger* to do concurrent file downloads.
Seems to be working as expected.
Only problem is that my logged status lines for each download are colliding with one another

**code snippet**

```
import sys, os, re
import threading
import requests
import queue
import logging
import time
import argparse

def download(session, url, filename):
    connection_pool.acquire()

    url = re.sub(r'/+$', '', url)
    filename = re.sub(r'^/+', '', filename)
    localpath = args.basepath + "/" + filename
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(localpath), exist_ok=True)
    full_url = url + "/" + filename + "?B"
    starttime = time.time()
    logger.info("Downloading {}".format(full_url))

    response = session.get(full_url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
    filesize = response.headers.get('Content-Length')

    with open(localpath, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)

    local_filesize = os.path.getsize(localpath)
    if (int(filesize) != int(local_filesize)):
        logger.error("File sizes do not match remote={} local={}".format(filesize, local_filesize))
        exit(1)
    endtime = time.time()
    elapsedtime = (endtime - starttime)
    bitrate = int(filesize) / elapsedtime
    logger.info("STATUS - file={} size={} time={} rate={} region={}".format(filename, filesize, elapsedtime, int(bitrate), args.region))
    connection_pool.release()

def setup_logger():
    hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
    hdlr.flush = sys.stdout.flush
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

... bunch of other functions ...
```

**output**:

```
895 2020-05-30 14:29:32,992 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3010A120200528.z
p?B 20-05-30 14:29:28,564 - get_files.py - INFO - STATUS - file=3066A120200528.zip size=9427150 time=8.5233154296875 rate=110604
2020-05-30 14:29:28,565 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3033A120200528.zip?
2020-05-30 14:29:29,610 - get_files.py - INFO - STATUS - file=3038A120200528.zip size=2472569 time=2.0577292442321777 rate=1201
00 2020-05-30 14:29:29,610 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3031A120200528.zi
?B 2020-05-30 14:29:29,836 - get_files.py - INFO - STATUS - file=3034A120200528.zip size=1441683 time=1.5025453567504883 rate=95
493 2020-05-30 14:29:29,836 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3030A120200528.z
p?B 2020-05-30 14:29:30,065 - get_files.py - INFO - STATUS - file=3037A120200528.zip size=3431121 time=2.3450839519500732 rate=14
3112 2020-05-30 14:29:30,065 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3029A120200528.
p?B 20-05-30 14:29:28,564 - get_files.py - INFO - STATUS - file=3066A120200528.zip size=9427150 time=8.5233154296875 rate=110604
2020-05-30 14:29:28,565 - get_files.py - INFO - Downloading https://10.12.134.17/3033A120200528.zip?
```

As shown above, the logger messages from some thread are colliding with others.

- Side note, this is running in an AWS ECS Fargate v1.4.0 container running amazonlinux:2 image and logging to an AWS Cloudwatch logstream with python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

While the reason it works does not make sense to me, the solution came while from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134586/python-logger-message-displayed-on-separate-line) post.  After completely removing the handler and just using the default handler, no more line collisions are occurring.